# Flutter JSON to object

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to use a file containing JSON data to populate my app, but I have the following error:
In my app screen:

```
Class Future<dynamic> has no instance getter 'popularGames'
```

In debug console:

```
 Unhandled Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'
E/flutter (23544): #0      new Game.fromJson (package:juego/src/data/game.dart:31:28)
```

And my code:
games.json

```
[
    {
        "id": "1234",
        "ownerId": "1",
        "name": "Dobble",
        "editor": "Spot it",
        "wished": 1,
    },
    {
        "id": "2345",
        "ownerId": "1",
        "name": "Jungle Speed",
        "editor": "Asmodee",
        "wished": 1,
    }
]
```

game.dart (line 31 is wished)

```
  class Game {
     late int id;
     late int ownerId;
     late String name;
     late String editor;
     late int wished;
   }
  Game.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = int.parse(json['id']);
    ownerId = int.parse(json['ownerId']);
    name = json['name'];
    editor = json['editor'];
    wished = int.parse(json['wished']);
   }
```

library.dart

```
class Library {
  List<Game> allGames = [];
  final List<Session> allSessions = [];

  loadJsonData() async {
    String jsonData = await rootBundle.loadString('lib/src/assets/json/games.json');
    //setState(() {
      allGames = json.decode(jsonData).map<Game>((dataPoint) => Game.fromJson(dataPoint)).toList();
    //});
  }
```

Comment: can you share the definition for Game, I feel that there's some issue with the fromJson

Comment: What does games.json look like?

Answer (score 1):

"wished" is already an int. No need to parse it. Either quote it, or remove `int.parse`

Answer (score 1):

In your `games.json` file to define int your should not put it inside "" .

replace the code in your `games.json` file by this :

```
[
    {
        "id": 1234,
        "ownerId": 1,
        "name": "Dobble",
        "editor": "Spot it",
        "wished": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2345,
        "ownerId": 1,
        "name": "Jungle Speed",
        "editor": "Asmodee",
        "wished": 1
    }
]
```

and replace your `game.dart` with this code :

```
class Game{
  final int id;
  final int ownerId;
  final String name;
  final String editor;
  final int wished;
  const Game({
    required id,
    required ownerId,
    required name,
    required editor,
    required wished
  });


  factory Game.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    return Game(
    id: json['id'],
    ownerId: json['ownerId'],
    name: json['name'],
    editor: json['editor'],
    wished: json['wished']
           );
         }


}
```